# Ignore "match" clause from query in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query with aggregations. One of the aggregation is on the field `starsCount`. There is a query clause that filters on the `starsCount` field along with other match clauses (hidden for clarity).

I wish for the `starsCount` aggregation to ignore the `starsCount` filtering in its results (the aggregation's result should be as if I had run the same query without the match clause on the `starsCount` field) while the other aggregation keeps its current behavior

Can this be done in a single query or should I use multiple ?

Here is the (simplified) query:

```
{
    [...]
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_service": {
            "comment": "keep current behaviour",
            "terms": {
                "field": "services",
                "size": 46
            }
        },
        "group_by_stars": {
            "comment": "ignore the filter on the starsCount field",
            "terms": {
                "field": "starsCount",
                "size": 100
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                [...] filters on other properties, non-relevant 
                {
                    "match": {
                        "starsCount": {
                            "query": "2"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think use should use multiple queries to achieve that. Elasticsearch first queries the data then performs aggregations on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this in single query by making use of [post filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html#search-request-post-filter) and [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html).
You need to follow the below steps to create the query:

1. Remove the `starsCount` match query from the main query as it should not affect the `group_by_stars` aggregation.
2. Since `starsCount` match query should filter the documents, move it to `post_filter`. Any query inside post_filter will filter the documents after calculating aggregations.
3. Now since `starsCount` is no more part of main query all the aggregations will not be affected by it. But what is required is that this filter should effect all other aggregations except `group_by_stars` aggregation. To achieve this we'll make use of filter aggregation and apply it to all the aggregations except `group_by_stars` aggregation.

The resultant query will be as below. (Note that instead of `match` query I have used `term` query. You can still use match but in this case term is a better choice.):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "some_other_agg":{
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "starsCount": "2"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "some_other_agg_filtered": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "some_other_field"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "group_by_service": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "starsCount": "2"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_service_filtered": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "services",
            "size": 46
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "group_by_stars": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "starsCount",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {...} //filter on other properties
      ]
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "starsCount": "2"
    }
  }
}
```